# How to Create extra menu's clicking "More" menu

Tags: android, menuitem, submenu, android-menu

I've more then 5 menu items, so i addded "More" as my menu item when i click this menu i
want more menu to be generate.

How can i do that ?

This is how i added

```
<item android:id="@+id/a" android:title="a" />
<item android:id="@+id/b" android:title="b" />
<item android:id="@+id/c" android:title="c" />
<item android:id="@+id/d" android:title="d" />
<item android:id="@+id/e" android:title="e" />
<item android:id="@+id/more" android:title="More" />
```

Comment: dnt need to create it .. it will automatically create submenu when you add more items, check after adding 9 or 10 items :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to create a `more` menu item, the android system will create it for you.

Just add 10 items, and it will work automatically.

Comment: this can be a comment daniel not an answer